# How can I count my textViews by a while loop?

Tags: java, android, loops, textview

I am programming a little app, where I get data as a string from a webserver. I split this string at regex. I never know before how many separated strings I will get.

On the main screen, I have 10 TextViews. I want to fill that textView with data from a webserver. But not every time there is data for every textView. I get the data as a string that I split into many strings but I never now before in how many (max. 10). So how can I set up a while loop counting my TextViews with a variable?

The TextViews in the layout has the names textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4 and so on. I guess the textView[n] in the java file is not the correct way to do that, but how?

```java
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
...

...
public void onResponseSuccessful(String processedResponse) {

   final String[] separated = processedResponse.split("Step: ");
   int n = separated.length;
   do {
      textView[n].append(separated[n]);
      n--;
   } while (n > 0);

// When I do it like that the TextView is underlined red, saying "Array type expected; found 'android.widget.TextView'
```

Comment: Better use android list view

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a ListView for that matter, but you can also do it your way:
(this example is with 3 textView but you can do it with 10)

```
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
private TextView textView3;

private TextView[] textViews = {textView1, textView2, textView3};

public void onResponseSuccessful(String processedResponse) {

    final String[] separated = processedResponse.split("Step: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
        if (i < separated.length) {
            textViews[i].setText(separated[i]);
            textViews[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            textViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that you need to init these TextViews with findViewById() or something..

Answer (score 0):

Are you already add textView1,textView2, ... to array[]
like this:

```
TextView[] textView = {textView1,textView2,....};

final String[] separated = processedResponse.split("Step: ");
int n = separated.length;
  do {
      textView[n].append(separated[n]);
      n--;
  } while (n > 0);
```